# python scrape a class href

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape the href link using python3

existing code:

```
import lxml.html
import requests

dom = lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Search?singleSearchBox=true&geo=191&pid=3825&redirect=&startTime=1576072392277&uiOrigin=MASTHEAD&q=the%20grilled%20cheese%20truck&supportedSearchTypes=find_near_stand_alone_query&enableNearPage=true&returnTo=https%253A__2F____2F__www__2E__tripadvisor__2E__co__2E__uk__2F__&searchSessionId=AF4BFA0308CF336B90FD9602FA122CD11576072382852ssid&social_typeahead_2018_feature=true&sid=AF4BFA0308CF336B90FD9602FA122CD11576072410521&blockRedirect=true&ssrc=a&rf=1').content)

result = dom.xpath("//a[@class='review_count']/@href")

print (result)
```

from this code:

```
<a class="review_count" href="/Restaurant_Review-g54774-d10073153-Reviews-The_Grilled_Cheese_Truck-Rapid_City_South_Dakota.html#REVIEWS" onclick="return false;" data-clicksource="ReviewCount">3 reviews</a>
```

with my existing code I'm getting empty print

i have located the link here yet:

```
widgetEvCall('handlers.openResult', event, this, '/Restaurant_Review-g54774-d10073153-Reviews-The_Grilled_Cheese_Truck-Rapid_City_South_Dakota.html', {type: 'EATERY',element: this,index: 0,section: 1,locationId: '10073153',parentId: '54774',elementType: 'title',selectedId: '10073153'});
```

so will need help on this , in this case will be even better to get locationId and selectedId to print

any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct URL? When I try to open that tripadvisor link and checked the source HTML, I did not see the link with the `class="review_count"` mentioned in the question.

Comment: me too, but for some reason i can see the link when inspect element

Comment: and was wondering if is possible to do that

Comment: or if that wont work , how can i do script to search by company name to get this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is because the data is loaded over javascript - try viewing the page with javascript disabled

You could try using a tool that will function with javascript eg. selenium - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Or try to track down where the JavaScript is loading the data from and then request that directly using python

Comment: ok, but is any way to scrape that link , or make some script to search that link for company name ?

Comment: unfortunately no luck :(